# Javascript : How to add operator to one object (not the whole class)?

Tags: javascript

do you know how to add an operator to an object (not to the whole class).
For a method, i know you can do that :

```
my_object.new_function = function(){return 1};
```

Then call `my_object.new_function()` return `1`.

But i would like to do that with the `get` operator to call `my_object.new_function` instead of `my_object.new_function()`.

Comment: [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 1):

There's a variety of ways -

```js
let m = {
  get x() {
    return 1
  }
}

console.log(m.x)
// 1

m = {
  ...m,
  get y() {
    return 2
  }
}

console.log(m.x, m.y)
// 1 2

Object.assign(m, { get z() { return 3 } })
console.log(m.x, m.y, m.z)
// 1 2 3
```

Getters are ordinary functions and so close over their environment -

```js
let m = {
  get x() { return 1 }
}

let a = 2

m = {
  ...m,
  get y() { return a } // <- dynamic
}

console.log(m.x, m.y)
// 1 2

a = 999

console.log(m.x, m.y)
// 1 999
```

Comment: Thanks for answers, i need it to be dynamic.

Testing your solution give me that :

```
var a=1;

Object.assign(empty, { get show_a() { return a } });

empty.show_a
1
a=4
4
empty.show_a
1
```

Comment: @DavidRouyre again, `Object.defineProperty()`

Comment: It makes the same problem :

var a=1;  

object1.property1 = a;  

console.log(object1.property1);  

a=5  

console.log(object1.property1);

Comment: No it doesn't. `Object.defineProperty(theObject, "propertyName", { get: function() ... });`

Comment: @DavidRouyre not sure what you did wrong. Getters are ordinary functions, I provided an example that allows for `a` to change and the getter reflects the change.